# jQuery foreach checkbox checked in tr > first td

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to iterate through the table rows and get the id and name of each checkbox checked in each tr in the first td and save it in a new Object() called values ex: values.id, values.name

Thanks

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="name1" checked="checked">
        </td>
        <td>
            Some input control 1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="2" type="checkbox" name="name2">
        </td>
        <td>
            Some input control 2
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you? And where are you stuck with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/paxux/1/)**

`aRecord` is an array of objects with each object containing both the name and ID of each checked checkbox found in the table.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var aRecord = [];
    $('#your_table input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        var oChkBox = {};
        oChkBox.name = $(this).attr('name');
        oChkBox.id = $(this).attr('id');
        aRecord.push(oChkBox);
    });

    var i = aRecord.length;
    while (i--) {
        alert("Name: "+ aRecord[i].name   + " ID: "+ aRecord[i].id);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/tracyfu/r6RMV/

```
var values = {};

$('tr input:checked').each(function(i) {
  values[i] = [];
  values[i].push($(this).attr('id'));
  values[i].push($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Will produce:

```
values = { [1, 'name1'] }
```

I'm leaving this solution as-is, since you specifically said you wanted to store the values in an `object` named `values`, but without knowing what you're going to do with the data, I would store the values in an array instead...

Comment: This will qualify on all input tags, rather than checked checkboxes. It's also a little less efficient because you're access the DOM twice for each row rather than incorporating it into your original jQuery selector.

Comment: @ElliotB. You're right. I didn't read the question thoroughly enough. Will emend. Thanks!

Comment: The HTML5 spec allows the value of the `id` attribute to be a number, but earlier versions didn't.

Comment: No way! That's actually pretty cool. This is exactly why I'm on SO, to learn stuff I wouldn't otherwise be looking for.